# IE not calling $.ajaxSetup

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

The following call works great in every browser but IE. `$.ajaxSetup` doesn't get recognized. The `error` and `complete` functions won't be called unless I add them directly into the `$.ajax` call.

Any idea why?

```
function setupAjaxCalls() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {
            deviceIdentifier: deviceIdentifier,
            deviceType: deviceType,
            memberId: loggedInMemberId,
            authToken: authToken,
            cache: false,
            responseFormat: 1
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            defaultError(x, e);
        },
        complete: function () {
            apiCallInProgress = 'false';
            //alert('complete!');
        }
    });
}

function logInForm(memLogin, memPassword, callback) {
    apiCallInProgress = 'true';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: baseApiUrl + '/MembershipService/AuthLoginSecure',
        data: {
            login: memLogin,
            password: memPassword,
            responseFormat: 0
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success == false) {
                apiError(data);
            } else {
                loggedInMemberId = data.Member.Id;
                authToken = data.Token;

                if (typeof (callback) != "undefined" || callback) {
                    callback(data);
                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok, so it's not your version. There was a bug in 1.4. Have you tried also adding success function to ajaxSetup?

Comment: It was there... but I'm using a callback in there that won't be called unless it's in each ajax call... separate problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

```
Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event
handler methods—.ajaxStart(), .ajaxStop(), .ajaxComplete(), .ajaxError(), .ajaxSuccess(),
.ajaxSend()—rather than within the options object for $.ajaxSetup().
```

You should move the error and complete properties into their own methods. :) Or, you can just put them into the $.ajax method. Whatever works best for your preferred code pattern!

Comment: I tried putting them in their own methods and they are not being called: `$(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
      defaultError(x, e);
    });`

Comment: Hmmm, well, you could just add the error and complete callbacks to the actual $.ajax calls. Then just have methods that you place inside the callbacks (both error and complete). To be honest, I have not idea where the default error function is coming from, so that may be an issue, too.

Comment: Maybe I'm declaring these incorrectly... can the `$.ajaxError` be declared before any `$.ajax` calls are made?

Comment: Not sure if you mean where you place it in the code, or if you mean prior to the event firing, but yes to both. Are you sure there is an error occurring?

Comment: I'm also using it with ajaxComplete and I'm 100% sure calls are being completed. `$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings){
       alert('complete!');
     });`

Comment: Well if it's completing, it's not going to fire the error method. :) How are you testing $.ajaxError?

Comment: Sorry... `ajaxComplete` is not being called in Firefox/Chrome/Safari when I know it completes and I'm testing in IE where I know it will fail, but `ajaxError` isn't called.

Comment: Would it mess up your code pattern to just use the error, complete, and success callbacks within $.ajax? It's hard to tell what might be breaking your $ajaxComplete and $ajaxError methods without seeing them in code-context. Try putting everything within $.ajax for now. If it works, you at least have a good place to refactor from.

Comment: It wouldn't mess anything up... I would just like it to be a bit cleaner. This will work for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Totally understand in regards to code cleanliness. At least you now have a working place to refactor from. :) Happy to help!